# How to prevent android/ios keyboard to resize my WEB-page?

Tags: android, ios, css, keyboard

I have a text area with autofocus. How to prevent keyboards to resize my window? It ruins my css.

Wanted behaviour: keyboard occupies the space where it has popped up (i have prepared space for it)

Any efficient solution or advice?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Or if that turns out to be difficult, at least a link to your website.